# Compose two pages from different sites without iframe

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, css

We have an ASP.NET MVC applikation, its layout page consists of two divs. The left side div contains a list of links to different pages which are opened in the right side div.

How we can add a link in the list to a page from another site which will be opened in the right side div like our sites pages without using iframe?

Comment: I don't think there's any good way to do that. You can download the source of the page with a server script and assign it to `rightDiv.innerHTML`, but lots of things won't work correctly.

Comment: Even if it could work, it's not a good idea. If it's not in an iframe, any JavaScript in the right side could access your site.

Comment: Tänkt you. So there is no solution but the iframe?

Comment: Not unless the content is very simple, with no relative URLs, JavaScript, or CSS style settings.